# I'm trying to get the value of an input but console is showing up empty

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of input but the console is showing up "undefine". What am I doing wrong?

```
<input name = "foo" value = "value">

<script>
var text = document.getElementsByName("foo").value;
console.log(text);
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsBy` returns a collection. I prefer to use `querySelector` to select a single element

Comment: @CertainPerformance But how do you use querySelector to get name.

Comment: `querySelector('[name="foo"]')`